# running spark on yarn as client

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run a spark job with yarn using:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class "KafkaToMaprfs" --master yarn --deploy-mode client /home/mapr/kafkaToMaprfs/target/scala-2.10/KafkaToMaprfs.jar
```

But facing this error:

> /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0 17/01/03 11:19:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader:
>   Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using
>   builtin-java classes where applicable 17/01/03 11:19:38 ERROR
>   SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended!
>   It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:124)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:530)
>           at KafkaToMaprfs$.main(KafkaToMaprfs.scala:61)
>           at KafkaToMaprfs.main(KafkaToMaprfs.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:752)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) 17/01/03 11:19:39 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is
>   not running Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended!
>   It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:124)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:530)
>           at KafkaToMaprfs$.main(KafkaToMaprfs.scala:61)
>           at KafkaToMaprfs.main(KafkaToMaprfs.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:752)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

I have a multi node cluster, i'm deploying the application from a remote node.
I'm using spark 1.6.1 and hadoop 2.7.x versions.

I didn't set the cluster, so I couldn't find where the mistake lies.

Can anyone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case i'm using MapR distribution.And i didn't configure the environment.
So, when i dug down to the all the conf folders.I made some changes in the below files,

**1. In Spark-env.sh,Make sure these values are set right.**

```
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=
export SPARK_PID_DIR=
export HADOOP_HOME=
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
export JAVA_HOME=
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS=
```

**2. yarn-env.sh.**

Make sure the yarn_conf_dir, and java_home are set with correct values.

**3. In spark-defaults.conf**

> ```
>  1.spark.driver.extraClassPath
>  2.set value for HADOOP_CONF_DIR
> ```

**4. HADOOP_CONF_DIR  and JAVA_HOME in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh**

```
1.export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/etc/hadoop
2.export JAVA_HOME =
```

**5.spark assembly jar**

> 1.Copy the following JAR file from the local file system to a world-readable location on MapR-FS: Substitute your Spark version and
>   specific JAR file name in the command.
>   /opt/mapr/spark/spark-/lib/spark-assembly--hadoop-mapr-.jar

Now i'm able to run my spark application as YARN-CLIENT smoothly using spark-submit.
These are basic essentials to make spark connect with yarn.
Correct me if i missed any other things.